# element not visible error for password field using protractor

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

I want to enter some values in the password field in but when i find the element and enter some values it is displaying element not visible error. below is what the html code for the password field.i have tried by xpath, css, id and name even i have made a wait condition but it is not working.

this is wat i have tried

```
browser.sleep(3000);
AGP.AgtPassword.sendKeys(Login.AgPassword);
var msg = AGP.pswmsg1.getText();
if(msg == Login.msg1 || Login.msg2)
{
AGP.AgtPassword.clear();
AGP.AgtPassword.sendKeys(Login.Ag1Password);
}

<input type="password" id="password" name="agtPassword" class="form-control text-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-touched" ng-model="agentPassPhrase" ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])/" placeholder="Password" required="" style="">
```

Comment: You need to figure out why that field is being reported as not visible. Finding by id is the best way to reference the element. That being said, if you have more than one field with that id value you are wrong. Per W3C specs, there can only be one element per page with a specific id value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some how i managed to solve this by below code.

this.AgtPassword = element.all(by.css(data.AgentPassword)).get(2);

Answer (score 2):

It is a guess, but one of the reasons for a problem like this is that there are multiple elements matching your locator and you are using the one that is not visible and not the one you actually want to send keys to. In this case you need to improve your locator. For instance, instead of doing:

```
element(by.id("password"));
```

you may need to make it search for the password field inside a specific element, for example:

```
element(by.css("form#myform password"));
```

Note that `id`s are only supposed to be unique across the page, but this is not always the case.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't agree. Finding by id is the single most accurate way to find an element. If he has two elements on the page with the same id then one of them needs to be changed. Per W3C specs, there can only be one id value per page.

Comment: @MBielski sure, W3C has it's rules. In practice, and I've seen multiple examples, it happens. Usually it happens when there are two forms with similar or same controls on a page  and one of the forms is hidden. In other words, it's not a wild guess but an educated guess.

Comment: so how can i find that the particular element is being used for another field.

Comment: @Lokesh you can check that manually using browser developer tools, or you can run `element.all(by.id("password")).count().then(function (count) { console.log(count) });`.

Comment: Thanks alecxe wll check this

Comment: thanks i have used...
this.password = element(by.id("login-password"));